# Geocoder - Service not available on Android 2.3

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked several times, but still I'm getting this error.

Tried both on emulator and actual device, triend chahging emulator's target to Google API and also changed the target build of the project to Google API's

Need help on these :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you solved it by now. As you said, there are many thread to it. After studying all the threads the answer I got was that Geocoder doesn't always return a value. You can try to send a request 3 times in a for loop. I might be able to return atleast once. If not then, their might be a connection issue or can be other issues like server does not reply to your request.

I had a while loop as well but I used to try it maximum for 10 times. Sometimes, it never returned anything even if it was connected to internet. Then, I used [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index) much more reliable way to get the address everytime:

I used to get the latitude and longitude and then request google servers, to reply with a JSON object containing various information about the location co-ordinates. This way of getting address string does not require Geocoder. Here is the function:

```
public JSONObject getLocationInfo() {

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=true");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

I called it as follows:

```
JSONObject ret = getLocationInfo(); 
JSONObject location;
String location_string;
try {
    location = ret.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0);
    location_string = location.getString("formatted_address");
    Log.d("test", "formattted address:" + location_string);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();

}
```

Hope this helps. I was also tired of relying on Geocoder. This worked for me. Though it might be just a little slower than geocoder. For testing its functionality, you can just place in the URL with the lat and longitude coordinates you are having. Try to see the returned JSON object in a web browser. You'll see how you can extract the address string. Try and read these threads as well:

[Geocoder doesn't always return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169189/geocoder-doesnt-always-return-a-value) and [geocoder.getFromLocationName returns only null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567216/geocoder-getfromlocationname-returns-only-null)

Comment: Is it the only way ? I have the same problem (Service not available) and my problem is that the google geocoder api is limited to 2,500 requests per day ...

Comment: @aat I am not sure of other ways that might be possible. Geocoder didn't always give me results. So, I used this and it has worked fine.

Comment: @aat If that seems a limit, they've provided [Google Maps API for Business](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/) that have a limit of 100,000 requests per day. Not sure if its free ;)

Comment: No, Google maps API Business is paying and this is the reason why I'm looking for an alternative to geocoder and google geocoding api

Comment: I didn't see anywhere they mentioned a limit on making HTTP requests. I'm curious to know what is stopping you to use the above method.

Comment: Here is the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits . They mentionned 2,500 requests per day

Comment: I apologize if i was not clear. I am saying that the above solution( in the answer) just makes an HTTP request to the maps API. Where does it use `Geocoder` API ? I think the limit is on using Geocoding? Isn't it ?

Comment: When you call `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=` with your httpGet, you are using the google gecoding api. From the doc `A Geocoding API request must be of the following form: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters`

Comment: Oh ya. Right. I missed it.