# Android geocoder can not find address,google maps can find

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

look here
https://www.google.com.tr/maps/place/Akbank+Sanat+Beyo%C4%9Flu/@41.0356243,28.9803398,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x14cab7643e33e919:0xad542d45132fe9ce?hl=en

it could find when i hit the search

```
Akbank Sanat istanbul
```

but when i use this code , it cant find:

```
  private LatLng getCoors(String loc, String desc){
    Log.v(TAG, "getCoors ");
    loc = loc +" Istanbul";

    if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "getCoors geocoder present");
        geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
       Log.v(TAG, "location: "+loc);

        try {
            From_geocode = geocoder.getFromLocationName(loc, 1);
            Log.v(TAG, "fromgeocode: "+From_geocode);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(TAG, "catched error - from geocode");//need to do something
        }

        if (!From_geocode.isEmpty()) {
            Log.v(TAG, " getcoors fromgeocod enot not empty  ");
            coors = new LatLng(From_geocode.get(0).getLatitude(), From_geocode.get(0).getLongitude());


            Log.v(TAG, "LATITUTE=====" + coors.latitude + "   LONGITUTE=====" + coors.longitude);
            return coors;
        }//second if end
        else{
            Log.v(TAG, " hata getcoors fromgeocode empty  ");
        }
    }//first if end
    else{
        Log.v(TAG, " hata getcoors geocoder not preset  ");
    }
    return null;
}//getcoors end
```

when i use same address,

```
else{
            Log.v(TAG, " hata getcoors fromgeocode empty  ");
        }
```

it goes here. SO, it means it cant fetch the address googlemaps can fetch.

What am i doing wrong? Is there easy way without using json or even not connecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the geocoder has issues accurately calculating locations in a single run. Try repeatedly asking for the location 5-10 times until a response is received.

Or, for a more accurate means of getting an address from a string, try implementing the following:

```
public JSONObject getLocationInfo() {

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=true");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

And calling it like this:

```
JSONObject ret = getLocationInfo(); 
JSONObject location;
String location_string;
try {
    location = ret.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0);
    location_string = location.getString("formatted_address");
    Log.d("test", "formattted address:" + location_string);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();

}
```

This code was from Shobhit Puri and the original question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182853/android-geocoder-getfromlocationname-always-returns-null).

Comment: should i only import json?