# how to get full address from passing Latitude and Latitude?

Tags: android, location

i used the code on my phone  bellow to get address { country, street, city}, but it didnt work for many inputs, why? and sometimes **crashing**. please how to get the **full address** by passing Longitude and Latitude to a method that returns all the available address to this Longitude and Latitude. can you please provide me with the answer to get best result. help me.

```
 import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Get_Location_Name extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private EditText ET1;
private EditText ET2;
private TextView TV1;
private Button B1;
static String result ="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.location_name);
    ET1=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.ET1_location_name);
    ET2=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.ET2_location_name);
    TV1=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.TV1_Location_name);
    B1=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.B1_Location_name);
    B1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    String s=null;
    if(!ET1.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !ET2.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
            if(this.isOnline())
            {

                for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
                {
                    s=getAddressFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(ET2.getText().toString()),
                    Double.parseDouble(ET1.getText().toString()),this);
                }
            if(s!=null)
                {
                Log.d("ssss","s"+s);
                TV1.setText(s);
                }
            else
                TV1.setText("s is null");
            }
            else
                TV1.setText("no internet connection");

    }
    else
        TV1.setText("Enter the Lat. and Lon.");



}

public boolean isOnline() {
   // code to check connectivity // it works fine(no problems)
}
```

here is the method that i want to modify

```
public static String getAddressFromLocation(final double lon,final double lat, final Context context) 
{

      Thread thread = new Thread() {
   @Override public void run() 
    {

       Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());   

       try {
           List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                   lat, lon, 1);
           if (list != null && list.size() > 0) 
               {
               Address address = list.get(0);
               result = " "+address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality()+","+address.getCountryName();
                   }
           } 
        catch (IOException e)
           {
           Log.e("fafvsafagag", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
           } 
    }
 };
 thread.start();
 return result;
  }

  }
```

please answer my question.

Comment: have you captured the logcat of when it crashes?

Comment: Check your connection. What type of crash, please, post your logs.

Comment: @chancea it crashes on my phone, the emulator never get the address always execute `Log.e("tag", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);` , and i don't why becouse i'm new to android

Comment: @MaximShoustin there is no problem with my connection because i got some address from different **Lon** and **Lat** such as 50_50, but i did not got address of many **Lon** , **Lat** such as 43_36

Comment: Do you know that when you give something like fafvsafagag in your log tag, you loose the ability to filter the millions of log messages that show up in logcat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue that Geocoder doesn't **always** returns a value. See [Geocoder doesn't always return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169189/geocoder-doesnt-always-return-a-value) and [geocoder.getFromLocationName returns only null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567216/geocoder-getfromlocationname-returns-only-null).  You can try to send a request 3 times in a for loop. It should be able to return atleast once. If not then, their might be a connection issue or can be other issues like server did not reply to your request. For me sometimes it never returned anything even if it was connected to internet. Then, I used [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index) much more reliable way to get the address everytime:

```
//lat, lng are Double variables  containing latitude and longitude values. 
public JSONObject getLocationInfo() {
        //Http Request
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=true");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
        }
                //Create a JSON from the String that was return.
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

I called the function as follows to get the complete address:

```
JSONObject ret = getLocationInfo(); //Get the JSON that is returned from the API call
JSONObject location;
String location_string;
//Parse to get the value corresponding to `formatted_address` key. 
try {
    location = ret.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0);
    location_string = location.getString("formatted_address");
    Log.d("test", "formattted address:" + location_string);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();

}
```

You can call this inside `AsyncTask` or a new thread. I used `Asynctask` for the same.
Hope this helps.This worked for me. If you replace the URL with the lat and longitude coordinates and see the returned JSON object in a web browser. You'll see what just happened.

Comment: your answer worked fine, but i have other questions such as the accuracy of the address provided by your code and why it did not get the full address info. can you provide me with a reference or link to understand your code. thank you for helping me.

Comment: In your browser, open `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=true"` link by replacing your latitude and longitude. You'll see a JSONArray with lots of addresses at different levels. You can select which one you want. The address accuracy also depends on accuracy of your latitude and longitude values.

Comment: I've mentioned in the answer from where the concept is explained. Here it is again: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index . Basically its sending a request to Google API's with latitude and longitude. The API returns a JSON array with addresses and you can parse the JSONArray to extract the address you want( city/Country/Street address).

Comment: No need to be sorry buddy. Its alright. Hope it helps you understand the concept.