# Geolocation in Android throwing exception when I search for the city (or anything rather than country name) works fine with country names

Tags: android, google-geocoder

When I search by country name, it works perfect, but when I search for the City or places, app crashes. Here is the code:

```
EditText location_tf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);
        String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
        //Toast.makeText(this, location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        double lat = add.getLatitude();
        double lng = add.getLongitude();

        gotoLocation(lat, lng, 4);
```

Comment: post exception trace with your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for the help, I found your answers help. 
My problem is solved, I was testing app on MIUI Chinese ROM, after installing MIUI international ROM, my code is working like a charm.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers provided over this SO threads

- [Android Geocoder getFromLocationName always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182853/android-geocoder-getfromlocationname-always-returns-null)
- [Geocoder doesn't always return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169189/geocoder-doesnt-always-return-a-value)
- [Geocoder doesn't always return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169189/geocoder-doesnt-always-return-a-value)

I would say that,
Geocoder doesn't always return a value. You need to try to send a request 3 times in a for loop. I should be able to return atleast once. If not then, their might be a connection issue or can be other issues like server dis not reply to your request.

You need to try something like below

```
try {
    List<Address> geoResults = geocoder.getFromLocationName("<address goes here>", 1);
    while (geoResults.size()==0) {
        geoResults = geocoder.getFromLocationName("<address goes here>", 1);
    }
    if (geoResults.size()>0) {
        Address addr = geoResults.get(0);
        myLocation.setLatitude(addr.getLatitude());
        myLocation.setLongitude(addr.getLongitude());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the details of any city or country just use the api defined [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) . The api is basically - `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=<yourCityName>&sensor=false`